# Load my customized fmri file folder with nifti files in the mentioned code

Tags: python, pytorch-dataloader

I am having a 20 4D processed fmri data in folder 'F:\New folder\cn_processed data\Sub1\S1.nii'.Sub1 folder has nifti file S1, similarly 20 folders for each subject. I want to include that data in the code mentioned below. I am new to python and struggling in basics and syntax. Kindly help me.

```
from monai.transforms import LoadImage
import torch
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def read_data(filename,load_root,save_root,subj_name,count,queue=None,scaling_method=None, fill_zeroback=False):
    print("processing: " + filename, flush=True)
    path = os.path.join(load_root, filename)
    try:
        # load each nifti file
        data, meta = LoadImage()(path)
    except:
        return None
    
    #change this line according to your file names
    save_dir = os.path.join(save_root,subj_name)
    isExist = os.path.exists(save_dir)
    if not isExist:
        os.makedirs(save_dir)
    
    # change this line according to your dataset
    data = data[:, 14:-7, :, :]
    # width, height, depth, time
    # Inspect the fMRI file first using your visualization tool. 
    # Limit the ranges of width, height, and depth to be under 96. Crop the background, not the brain regions. 
    # Each dimension of fMRI registered to MNI space (2mm) is expected to be around 100.
    # You can do this when you load each volume at the Dataset class, including padding backgrounds to fill dimensions under 96.
   
    background = data==0
    
    if scaling_method == 'z-norm':
        global_mean = data[~background].mean()
        global_std = data[~background].std()
        data_temp = (data - global_mean) / global_std
    elif scaling_method == 'minmax':
        data_temp = (data - data[~background].min()) / (data[~background].max() - data[~background].min())

    data_global = torch.empty(data.shape)
    data_global[background] = data_temp[~background].min() if not fill_zeroback else 0 
    # data_temp[~background].min() is expected to be 0 for scaling_method == 'minmax', and minimum z-value for scaling_method == 'z-norm'
    data_global[~background] = data_temp[~background]

    # save volumes one-by-one in fp16 format.
    data_global = data_global.type(torch.float16)
    data_global_split = torch.split(data_global, 1, 3)
    for i, TR in enumerate(data_global_split):
        torch.save(TR.clone(), os.path.join(save_dir,"frame_"+str(i)+".pt"))


def main():
    # change two lines below according to your dataset
    dataset_name = 'ABCD'
    load_root = '/storage/4.cleaned_image' # This folder should have fMRI files in nifti format with subject names. Ex) sub-01.nii.gz 
    save_root = f'/storage/7.{dataset_name}_MNI_to_TRs_minmax'
    scaling_method = 'z-norm' # choose either 'z-norm'(default) or 'minmax'.

    # make result folders
    filenames = os.listdir(load_root)
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(save_root,'img'), exist_ok = True)
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(save_root,'metadata'), exist_ok = True) # locate your metadata file at this folder 
    save_root = os.path.join(save_root,'img')
    
    finished_samples = os.listdir(save_root)
    queue = Queue() 
    count = 0
    for filename in sorted(filenames):
        subj_name = filename[:-7] 
        # extract subject name from nifti file. [:-7] rules out '.nii.gz'
        # we recommend you use subj_name that aligns with the subject key in a metadata file.

        expected_seq_length = 1000 # Specify the expected sequence length of fMRI for the case your preprocessing stopped unexpectedly and you try to resume the preprocessing.
        
        # change the line below according to your folder structure
        if (subj_name not in finished_samples) or (len(os.listdir(os.path.join(save_root,subj_name))) < expected_seq_length): # preprocess if the subject folder does not exist, or the number of pth files is lower than expected sequence length. 
            try:
                count+=1
                p = Process(target=read_data, args=(filename,load_root,save_root,subj_name,count,queue,scaling_method))
                p.start()
                if count % 32 == 0: # requires more than 32 cpu cores for parallel processing
                    p.join()
            except Exception:
                print('encountered problem with'+filename)
                print(Exception)

if __name__=='__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    end_time = time.time()
    print('\nTotal', round((end_time - start_time) / 60), 'minutes elapsed.')
```

How to include my datas in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to load a NIfTI image in python would be to use nilearn's load_img function:
https://nilearn.github.io/stable/modules/generated/nilearn.image.load_img.html#nilearn.image.load_img

Simply run:

```
from nilearn.image import load_img
nifti_image = load_img("path/to/nifti_file.nii")
```

To get the data use the `get_fdata()` method which returns a numpy array:

```
data = nifti_image.get_fdata()
```

Learn more about nilearn here:
https://nilearn.github.io/stable/index.html

PS: If you want to do multiprocessing you may want to look into joblib:
https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need to incorporate my data in that particular code. Can you help me how to define load_root, save_root and subj_name

Comment: As far as I can tell those should be paths, so you can define them as paths. Without more context as to what exactly you mean by incorporating them in your code, I don't think I can help you. I guess the current error in your code is that these paths are defined as hard coded Unix like paths but you are using windows so the paths should be defined as windows paths or more generic using pathlib https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html